# What is the difference between display server, a window manager, and a compositor. X windows Vs Wayland

Tags: linux, x11, wayland

I am trying to understand Wayland protocol but can't grasp that a window manager tells display server where each windows are. So is display server a renderer or compositor?

Comment: Window manager doesn't know how to place windows or handle events in them. That's the server. It requests these services from the server. Then most of what it does is add some borders a titlebar. I'd study the Xlib functions if I were you. Plenty of docs. Then try your hand at some basic functionality, e.g. draw a window using the Xlib primitives, and make it work like an (sort of) ambilight: have it average the colors from the entire display and make that the (dynamic) background color of the window. Really fun.

Comment: Rendering (no **alpha**) and compositing (with **alpha**) are basically the same thing.  **alpha** is a term for transparency.  The original X protocols would not 'composite' or combine two windows.  If all windows are opaque, then you only need a painters algorithm or other to render.  Ie, paint back (z depth) to front, or calculate visible regions and only request redraws of those regions.  With **alpha**, you need to draw everything Z-ordered and apply alpha.  Many frameworks keep off screen buffer for application windows and then composite the 'off screen' data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been searching for the answer myself for quite some time now as well.

I will try to provide a partial answer.

Reading the [official docs](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/architecture.html) it seems to me that, using the wayland protocol, the display server, window manager, and the compositor become one single program.

For example, `xorg` is a display server, `i3` is a window manager, `picom` is a compositor but `sway` is all three.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use answere to ask a question. (I know, can't comment yet). So ask an own question.

Comment: @rasmusmerzin   You may include my information in your answer if you wish.  I think he did answer parts of the question.  Also, the question has been open for four years without an answer.  Another key difference is Wayland is not supporting remote desktops.  For most people this does not matter, but it can be quite useful with 'X'.  You can always `ssh` to console, but the ability to run graphics application is sometimes great for remote work.  You need to make these decision (what graphics stack to use) when creating embedded Linux filesystems; for instance, Yocto, etc.

Comment: The only remaining topic is how to integrate an OpenGL graphics stack.  Wayland does this much more directly, so the foot print is smaller.  As the graphics card is on the client and you need all window data to composite, the amount of data between client and server is far larger when compositing.  The graphic card can composite two windows without the CPU.  Compositing is expensive to do in CPU and the system may seem slow on an embedded device.